# React-Data-Grid only displays 9 rows

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am loading a react-data-grid with a data source that is populated row by row (a row is added once a second).  Once it gets to 9 rows it stops adding rows.  I am also having another problem where the grid will not show up until I change the zoom on the screen.  It is blank beforehand.  Here is my grid element

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import 'react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.css';

const columns = [
  { key: 'timeStamp', name: 'Date/Time' },
  { key: 'gpsAccuracyValue', name: 'GPS Accuracy' },
  { key: 'speedMph', name: 'Speed' },
  { key: 'battery', name: 'Battery' },
  { key: 'id', name: 'id' },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 0, title: 'Example' },
  { id: 1, title: 'Demo' }
];

class TestGrid extends Component {


render(){
    return (
        <div>
        <DataGrid
          columns={columns}
          rows={this.props.data}
          rowsCount={this.props.data.length}
          minHeight={500}
        />
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default TestGrid;
```

I pass in the data like this

```
<TestGrid data={this.props.deviceData} />
```

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in  codesandbox. Then, It would be easy to see problem and provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-khayyam-hfzmq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Adding `style={{ height:500 }}` seems to have fixed a similar problem I was having and displays more than 9 rows.

Comment: This was for version: 7.0.0-canary.33